# Get Blobs with no metadata

Tags: azure, storage, metadata, azure-blob-storage

I am setting blob metadata of all the blobs in a container using an azure function. But due to huge number of blobs the function time outs. If I run the function again it again starts getting the blobs which already have metadata. Is there a way in which I can get only the blobs which do not have metadata?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only want to fetch blobs that don’t have metadata. Correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

The question does not contain examples, but maybe it is possible to specify parameters in the call to get more accurately what you want?

Comment: This is not really an answer but rather a comment.

Comment: var response = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix, true, BlobListingDetails.None, 200, continuationToken, null, null);
                continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
I am getting all blobs in the set of 200

Comment: maybe try lowering the 200 number and filter the metadata out afterwards, at least you are less likely to have a timeout

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in which I can get only the blobs which do not have
>   metadata?

It is not possible to do so. Azure Blob Storage does not have server-side filtering capability on metadata. In fact, only thing you could perform server-side filter is on blob name prefix. What you need to do (and this is something you're already doing) is list all blobs and then filter out the blobs with no metadata in your function code.

```
var response = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix, true, BlobListingDetails.None, 200, continuationToken, null, null); continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
```

I noticed that in your code above you are only fetching 200 blobs at a time. This is not really efficient. In a single request to Azure Blob Storage, you can ask Storage Service to return a maximum of 5000 blobs. If you change this 200 to 5000, then the number of requests that you'll make to Storage will reduce considerably and there's a possibility that you will be able to get all blobs before the function times out.